# Chrome doesn't obey no-cache rule in static HTML files

Tags: html

I have a bunch of HTML static files. I realize chrome doesn't really obey the rules in my HTML static file.

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
```

Seems to be bug? http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=28035

I do not know any workaround. Anyone knows?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development

Comment: Those are settings being done by developer himself at his own desktop side. My major concerns is end users. As every time when I update the content of my static html, my end users still get old pages in chrome, due to explicitly caching done by chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your web server to send these as headers for your file (or all *.html files).
Since you didn't specify your web server, can't really give more info.

Comment: Sorry. I do not have control over the web server. I just host those file in a very simple web hosting service, provided by sourceforge

Comment: @YanChengCHEOK so what makes you think that that hosting service is making web browsers cache this file?

Comment: Simple. I just open up chrome and key in the desired URL. Then chrome is still showing up old content, although I had already updated html files to new content. No. This is not issues on hosting service. Is the issues, chrome doesn't obey no-cache meta tag.